# Is there a way to see which functions/executions are taking longest?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

There is a certain spot on my page (a jquery based web-app) where it kind of hangs. Are there any tools that would quickly determine if there's a specific place it's getting tripped up?

It is on localhost right now, which may alter what tools would be applicable. (I'm not talking about load time, but rather execution time)

Comment: what server side language are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebug for Firefox and Developer Console for Chrome both have built in script profiling tools that will help you identify slow logic in your JavaScript programs.

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript)?

Comment: yes. haven't noticed that feature, and saw a few other similar posts mentioning that firebug did not have the tools to assist in this area.

Answer (score 1):

There is jQuery [deep profiling plugin](http://ejohn.org/blog/deep-profiling-jquery-apps/) by John Resig. There's also this article from him that talks about [Function Call profiling](http://ejohn.org/blog/function-call-profiling/).

There is also this great tool called [dynaTrace](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/content/capabilities.aspx) which gives you the ability to profile in IE (and FF). It provides lot more than simple JS profiling (like DOM rendering measurement) and is quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use Firebug, just call:

> console.time("timing foo");

Before executing the code you want to measure and:

> console.timeEnd("timing foo");

Afterwards. That in a low-fi approach.

The high-fi would be just call `console.profile()` before the code you want to measure, and then `console.profileEnd()` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

[DynaTrace](http://www.dynatrace.com) is by far the best thing I have seen out there... its Free to use too.. And the best part is it works for IE too where the performance is worst hit. A brilliant application with all performance measures.. needs a little bit of learning but once you are used to it there is nothing like it out there...

it also measures network time in ajax requests.. apart from this the rendering time etc.. it can go deep into JS libraries like Jquery..

Try it!!